# Under what conditions is Apple's 'advertisingIdentifier' reset?

Tags: ios, ios6, udid

Other than the user manually resetting it, has anyone observed other things that will cause the ADID to be reset? OTA OS Upgrades? iTunes Restores?

Comment: OS upgrades or format a device.

Comment: @Divyu Source? I highly doubt that OS upgrades will reset the Advertising Identifier...

Answer (score 86, accepted):

(effects on `advertisingIdentifier` and `identifierForVendor`, as tested on an iPhone 3GS with iOS 6.0.1 and iOS 6.1.3 and an iPhone 4S with iOS 6.1.3 and iOS 7.0.0)

- **"Reset All Settings" in iOS Settings app**
   No effect
- **"Erase All Content and Settings" in iOS Settings app**
   Resets both `advertisingIdentifier` and `identifierForVendor`.
- **Restoring a device via iTunes**
   Resets both `advertisingIdentifier` and `identifierForVendor`.
- **Deleting an app from the device**
   Resets `identifierForVendor`, if this was the last app with a specific Team ID.
- **Updating an app (automatically or via App Store)**
   No effect
- **Updating an app via TestFlight or Ad-Hoc**
   May reset the `identifierForVendor`, according to documentation.
- **Enabling/disabling "Limit Ad Tracking"**
   iOS 6.0.1: No effect
  iOS 6.1.3: Resets the `advertisingIdentifier`.
- **System Update OTA (iOS 6.0.1 to iOS 6.1.3)**
   No effect
- **System Update OTA (iOS 6.1.3 to iOS 7.0.0)**
   Resets the `identifierForVendor` in some cases. (1)
- **System Update via iTunes (iOS 6.1.3 to iOS 7.0.0)**
   Resets the `identifierForVendor` in some cases. (1)
- **"Reset Advertising Identifier" in iOS Settings app**
   Resets the `advertisingIdentifier`. If some running (or suspended) apps already
  requested a `advertisingIdentifier`, they will not be able to
  retrieve the new one until they are stopped and relaunched.
- **Backup via iTunes**
   No effect
- **Restore of a Backup via iTunes (to the same device)**
   Restores the backed-up settings, including both `advertisingIdentifier` and
  `identifierForVendor`. Note: If you delete multiple apps with some
  Team ID before the restore, the `identifierForVendor` will never be
  reset again until you reinstall all apps with that Team ID you had
  installed and delete them again. This seems to be a bug.
- **Restore of a Backup via iTunes (to a different device)**
   Resets both `advertisingIdentifier` and `identifierForVendor`.

(1) As far as I understand, this should not happen with Apps in the App Store. It seems to be related to the number of components in the app's bundleID and the respective provisioning profile: [iOS 7 App Release Notes regarding App Deployment](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/RN-iOSSDK-7.0/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013202-CH1-SW7)
In my tests, the `identifierForVendor` in apps with 4 components *did* change (for versions with either developer or enterprise distribution provisioning profiles), but *did not* change for those with 3 components.

Comment: Great info. Do you know if performing a system update via iTunes is functionally equivalent to "Restoring a device via iTunes" in this case?

Comment: I found that toggling "Limit Ad Tracking" (either on or off) changed the advertisingIdentifier each time (on iOS 6.1.3).

Comment: @MusiGenesis You're right. Apple actually changed this behaviour between the two versions, and I didn't catch that. Verified in the iOS Simulator and fixed in the answer. Thanks! :)

Comment: @Andreas Ley Hi Andreas, if I restore a backup to a different device, can I still get the same ADID and VendorID on the new device?

Comment: @MasterBeta Both identifiers seem to be reset after a restore to a different device.

Comment: @RandyDailey After more tests, it looks like a system update via iTunes is equivalent to an OTA update.

Comment: So.. is there any way to **identify uniquely a device** from within an iOS app since advertising identifier will not do the trick? Note that no user registration system is used

Comment: @GeorgePligor The closest you can get is abusing the iOS keychain to store an identifier when the app is launched for the first time. Keychain items aren't removed when the app is uninstalled and kept between system updates. However, when a user completely wipes the device, this information is lost, too. Apple is working hard to make sure that you can't uniquely identify a device, so the keychain trick might stop working at some point, too.

Comment: Have you looked at the difference for vendor ID when updating from AppStore version to apple testflight?

Comment: @MatthieuRouif According to documentation, the `identifierForVendor` may change in this situation. However, I haven't tested that.

Comment: How about updating to iOS 8.4? Do you think it changed the value?

Comment: @KarenAnne I don't know and I can't test it at the moment. However, I would advise you to follow Apple's recommendation: *"you should gracefully handle situations where the identifier changes"*.

Answer (score 4):

Two cases:

- Manually choosing “Reset Advertising Identifier”. But if the app is running in the background, the identifier will remain active until the application is relaunched.
- Manually choosing “Reset All Content and Settings”.

Backups, OS upgrades, app re-install, or choosing “Limit Ad Tracking” won't reset the identifier.

AFAIK you could send the vendor ID and the advertising ID to the server, and when the user resets the advertising ID with “Reset Advertising Identifier”, you can match the new with the old one, because the vendor ID survives. No idea how Apple intends to prevent this.

Answer (score 1):

There is no official, definitive list from Apple. The documentation only states:

> This identifier may change—for example, if the user erases the device—so you should not cache it.

Apple don't give any further detail. It's known that resetting the device changes the ADID, as does the user manually resetting it themselves (where this feature is available, so iOS 6.1+).  I've not been able to find anything that suggests an OS update would reset the identifier.

It is of course possible other, undocumented behaviour resets the identifier, but I've not been able to find anything else.